# Error with exit value: {function_clause,[{inet,tcp_close,[[]]},{}]}, I am getting this error in my server when client runs more than 5 minutes?

Tags: erlang, network-programming

I am spawning my server each time whenever a client connects. But if the client is running  considerable time with server i.e multiple times, regularly I am getting the ***" Error in process <0.111.0> with exit value: {function_clause,[{inet,tcp_close,[[]]},{run_server,function,8}]}".*** I think it is from inet options.... please any one can give some idea to overcome the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing in an empty list to `inet:tcp_close/1` instead of a port.

Comment: Not without arguments, but with an empty list. Otherwise he would be getting an undef error and the stack trace would show `{inet,tcp_close,[]}` rather than `{inet,tcp_close,[[]]}`.

Comment: Thanks for being more thorough than I am.